# Bash Piping PV - move file and (un)tar

Tags: bash, pipe, tar

I'm having my first real introduction to injecting 'pv' ([Pipe Viewer](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml)) in bash for some user feedback. I've also tried to search the other posts regarding PV and haven't found what I needed. It is likely a simply answer that others will hopefully find useful ...

My goal is to transfer (a large network file) then decompress (in this case tar)

The network folder has been mounted for convenience.  I'm able to

```
pv /root/networkshare/someFile.tar > /tmp/someFile.tar
```

then

```
pv someFile.tar | tar xf -
```

So I'm trying to pipe chain them and just can't seem to get it correct. I believe I'm close with

```
pv -cN transfer /root/networkshare/someFile.tar > /tmp/someFile.tar | pv -cN untar tar xf -
```

Just an FWIW, if I create a dependent instruction it does work, I'm really trying to understand more of the piping construct. For example provided the network transfer is successful, the following will produce the desired result:

```
pv -cN transfer /root/networkshare/someFile.tar > /tmp/someFile.tar && pv -cN untar /tmp/someFile.tar | tar xf -
```

I'd appreciate that final "nudge" and what I'm missing. Thanks as always.

Comment: @AaronDigulla A fantastic utility http://www.catonmat.net/blog/unix-utilities-pipe-viewer/

Comment: I can't imagine what the -1 is for, but thanks ever so much.

Comment: ... Why not just `pv /root/networkshare/someFile.tar | tar x` ?

Comment: @Kevin only because i'm looking to monitor both the network transfer portion separate from the "untarring", otherwise certainly.

Comment: That really makes no sense. The rate going into tar is going to be exactly the same as the rate coming off the network (almost certainly limited by network speed). And if you do them both in one pipeline like that, you get to skip the extra, unnecessary, temporary file.

Comment: The file is not necessarily in a 'tar' format, it is often in a compressed format for transfer. The above was for simplification purposes. In fact, most often the files are in a pbzip2 form and multiple processors are used for the decompression which is almost always at a different pace than network throughput.

Comment: @EdT In a scenario where you transfer data over the network and decompress on the other side the bottleneck is most likely always the network and you cannot decompress faster than data arrives, so the theoretical throughput of the decompressing tool does not matter. But maybe I don't understand the point of your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a quick thank you to @Aaron for forcing me to consider the fundamental difference between stdin | stdout and redirection. As he stated, when you > the stdout, you are "done".

Specific to PV piping, there are some overload uses that were causing me some confusion, specifically when used as follows:

```
pv infile > outfile
```

here pv acts like 'cat'.  What you should consider is the non-overload function call as follows (psuedo)

```
command1 | pv | command2
```

Here pv simply acts as a utility that measures progress (if it knows the expected metric). I'll provide what I needed and break it down.

The final bash command is:

```
pv -cN transfer /root/networkshare/someFile.tar | pv -cN untar -s $(du -sb /root/networkshare/someFile.tar | awk '{print $1}') | tar xf - -C /tmp/someDir/
```

It is MUCH less complicated than it looks and I will break it down:
We start with the transfer which uses stdin -> stdout. We want to pipe the transfer in to the next command (un)tar so we want it to remain in stdout. By using pv we are able to monitor that progress, and pass in the file. Here pv will grab the file size so it can calculate the ETA. This is effectively command1 as here pv is acting as 'cat'.

This 'cat' pipes stdout to the next bit,

```
....pv -cN untar -s $(du -sb /root/networkshare/someFile.tar | awk '{print $1}')
```

as this is taking the stdout of the first section, pv does not know the file size yet. To get some meaningful ETA, we simply get the original file size with the 'du' call and pass it as an '-s' in to pv. Here pv is acting in the more classic middle man as shown above between command1 (cat) and command2 (tar).

Then we pass this all to the tar process and identify our desired final destination of decompressed data.

For large files this utility is fantastic at giving some understanding of what is going on.

Comment: What do you mean by `pv acts like 'cat'`? Using the example `command  1 | pv | command 2`, what would the construct `tar -czvf tar.gz somefiles`?

Answer (score 0):

If you write `cmd > file | cmd2`, then `cmd2` will get nothing since the `> file` already directed all output of `cmd` into `file`.

Try `tee`:

```
cmd | tee file | cmd2
```

`tee` makes a copy of all input into a file and then passes the standard input on to the next process in the pipe.

Comment: That doesn't seem like the right approach, most especially if it is going to make a copy of all input on large files. Thank you for your perspective though.

Comment: How do you plan to get a copy of a data in `file` without making a copy of it? :-)

Comment: @AaronDigulla - Do you mean to say that the `pv` command should be constructed as `command 1 | pv | command 2`? If yes, what would the construct `tar -czvf file.gz somefiles` be?